# Rails truncating of parameters with '.' in urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, escaping

I am trying to send an IP address as a parameter to a Rails method `destroy` in a url. There is a problem if the parameter includes `.`; I get `not found` errors, this is the log generated:

```
Started DELETE "/admin/user/stefan-admin/whitelist/4.3.2.1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-17 09:31:18 +0100
Processing by ErrorsController#error_404 as 
  Parameters: {"not_found"=>"admin/user/stefan-admin/whitelist/4.3.2"}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Session: {:user=>"admin", :role=>:admin, :user_id=>"stefan-admin"}
Completed 404 Not Found in 30ms (Views: 1.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

The `not found` message has a truncated ip address. If I use a parameter without `.`, e.g. `abc`, I don't get the `not found` error, and the `destroy` method is called.

Rails received the url, but then mangled it internally, possibly because it is processing `.` as an extension. Is there some way to turn off this behaviour or escape the url to avoid it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a constraint to the routes to allow dots in params

resources :whitelists, :constraints => { :id => /[0-9.]+/ }

Or something of that kind in your routes.rb, it depends on how you write your routes but the constraints part stay the same

Comment: This works!  I've accept this answer over the others since it fits in nicely with the current construction of the routes.rb file.

Comment: Beautiful! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

The reason for the "truncated" ip address is the (optional) `(.:format)` that `resources`, 'get', 'match' etc. generate on every route.

You can specify a dedicate route without the format like:

```
match '/admin/user/:id/whitelist/*ip', to: 'controller#action', format: false
```

pay attention to the `*` at the last parameter. It collects the whole rest of the url.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance the problem could be resolved by manipulating the parameters or routing. By thinking a bit more, you will notice two more problems in your scheme:

1. You used GET request to process a delete action
2. The dots in url, if not for name extension, is very ugly.

So, instead of solving the problem directly, I suggest you to:

Review the view code containing the request link. It's better to be a `button_to`, or a `link_to` with `delete` method and UJS support.

By this you'll send a POST request to server without ip in URL. And you don't need any change in controller code.

Comment: I'm confused...surely I'm using a 'delete' action?

Comment: @Stefan, you may define it as delete but you get the params from URL and there is a warning "WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity" so I think there is no form in your view and your link works as a GET request.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  I'm new to this codebase so I'm not in a position to make big restructurings yet, but things like this are useful to know for when I'm more familiar with the code and want to tidy it later.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found a hacky way to do it. If your route looks like this

```
match 'controller/:some_param' => 'controller#action'
```

Then in the controller action, you can do something like this

```
actual_param = params[:some_param]
if params[:format]
  actual_param << "." << params[:format]
end
```

Then use actual_param to identify the correct resource

Comment: This gives me an error `ActionController::UnknownFormat` for this line: `respond_to do |format|`